# Setting data attribute on stripe button

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I can't figure this out. I checked other questions regarding setting data attributes, seems to be a tricky enough thing.

The stripe button amount is purely for aesthetics, I'm trying to set it ('data-amount') each time a user updates the quantity select box.

Every time I change the quantity select an alert gives the correct amount and if I inspect the dom the 'data-amount' attribute appears to be set correctly but when I click the stripe button the modal shows the default data-amount, i.e nothing.

Anyone know how to do this?

view (form, select input not shown)

```
<div class="stripe-controls" align="center">
  <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
      data-key="ENV['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] %>" data-amount="">
  </script>
</div>
```

coffeescript

```
$ ->
  $('#order_quantity').click(orderTotal)
  orderTotal()

orderTotal = ->
  quantity = $('#order_quantity').val()
  price = $('#ticket-price').data('url')
  total = quantity * price
  $('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', total)
  alert total
```

Comment: Not a coffee script master at all, but shouldn't the `orderTotal` be defined before you use it?

Comment: I think this line here `$('.stripe-button').attr('amount', total)` should be `$('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', total)`

Comment: @gdoron: It should. This is the JS that it generates http://pastebin.com/wvx96826

Comment: @ace. Yeah, just wrote the same thing but `data` is the preferred function for it.

Comment: Should'nt it actually be: `$('.stripe-button').data('amount', total);`?

Comment: @gdoron yes, that's correct. :)

Comment: sorry that was my typo, seems like it's all academic anyhow, thanks for all the replies!

Comment: See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080786/7618391) for an easy quick fix to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify a custom amount using  [`StripeCheckout.open()`](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).

Note: I work at Stripe.

Comment: Thanks Alex, appreciate the quick answer.

Comment: is there on success & on cancellation functions? just like opened & closed functions